# Free memory from pointer to chars array

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc, free

I try to free the memory of pointer to chars array.
I didn't get error but when i check with Dr.Memory i have :

```
      1 unique,    13 total unaddressable access(es)
      0 unique,     0 total uninitialized access(es)
      1 unique,     1 total invalid heap argument(s)
      0 unique,     0 total GDI usage error(s)
      0 unique,     0 total handle leak(s)
      0 unique,     0 total warning(s)
      1 unique,     1 total,      8 byte(s) of leak(s)
      0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of possible leak(s)
```

My Code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define SIZE_NAME 20

    int main(void)
    {
        int players, i, j;
        char** p_Array = NULL;
        char name[SIZE_NAME];

        printf("Enter number of players in basketball: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &players);

        p_Array = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * players); // array with [players] cells.
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_NAME; i++)
            *(p_Array + i) = (char*)malloc((SIZE_NAME + 1) * sizeof(char));

        for (i = 0; i < players; i++)
        {
            printf("Enter name for player number %d: ", i + 1);

            fflush(stdin); // clear buffer
            gets(name);
            strcpy(*(p_Array + i), name);
        }


        for (i = 0; i < players; i++)
        {
            printf("Name of player number %d is %s \n", i + 1, *(p_Array + i) );
        }

        for (i = 0; i < players; i++)
            free(*(p_Array + i)); // delete the array from the RAM. 
        getchar();  
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The C standard specification says that `fflush(stdin)` is *undefined behavior*. While some libraries allow it as an extension don't do it if you want to be portable. And don't, ever, use `gets` to read a string. It's dangerous, was deprecated in the C99 standard, and removed completely from the C11 standard.

Comment: You forgot to free `p_Array`

Comment: And on another unrelated note, you do know that e.g. `*(p_Array + i)` is the same as `p_Array[i]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong loop bound for this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_NAME; i++)
    *(p_Array + i) = (char*)malloc((SIZE_NAME + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

The loop should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < players; i++)
    ...
```

Comment: ..and `free(p_Array)`

Comment: Ouuu, Thank you ! :)